# Transferring arbitrary data via Bluetooth Smart (BLE) with nRF51

Tags: embedded, bluetooth, low-power, data-transfer

I was wondering if it was possible to **send arbitrary packets** of data over a *Bluetooth Smart* (Low Energy, 4.0) link from a nRF51 (Nordic Semi, BLE compliant SoC) to a phone?

Also if you don't know the specific device, *any help* is appreciated as all I found about Bluetooth Low Energy are pre-configured profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, on the nRF51 you can indeed send arbitrary L2CAP data, although you cannot send arbitrary ATT or SMP packets, those 2 protocols are reserved by the stack. But you can select an unused L2CAP channel and, if you control both sides, send any data you want.

Comment: And what about the other side? I mean, can I process arbitrary packets through iOS SDK and Android? All I could find was interfacing under pre-established profiles

Comment: No, unfortunately those APIs don't give you anything beyond standard ATT. However, you can always craft your own payloads in ATT packets, using 128-bit UUIDs for your characteristics, and transfer whatever data you want in whatever format you want there.